# Loading Tensorflow model in c#

Tags: c#, tensorflow

I am really struggling with the fact that i don't know how can I load and use a TensorFlow image classifier model in c#.

To be more precise I want to use a model trained in [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image) that can be exported in multiple TensorFlow formats.
And if possible an example code will be really helpful.

I have tried to ask the same question but it got closed, I really need to find out how can I load and use the model so please let the question open. Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do with this model in c# code? Why do you need to import it into c# project?

Comment: @picolino Because I want to use it for detecting hand position form the web cam. (closed, open, etc)

Comment: I mean do you want to only run model or want to train it?

Comment: @picolino Just to run it. (Sorry for the late response)

Answer (score 3):

If you need only to evaluate model in C# code, then you need some lightweight library that can be used as loader and evaluator for your network.

There are many good libraries to work with tensorflow models in C#, like:

- [TensorFlowSharp](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp)
- [TensorFlow.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET)

Unfortunately, all existing libraries has pre-defined logic for training model too, so that is a little ballast for your task.

To accomplish your purposes, please see this [detailed article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5164135/TensorFlow-Creating-Csharp-Applications-using#csharpconsole_loadmodel) about how to load TF model into your C# application using TensorFlowSharp.

Comment: When i use the example in the article i get the error TensorFlow.TFException: 'Invalid GraphDef' at the graph.Import(buffer). Here are some photos with the file that i got from Teachable Machine: [1](https://ibb.co/3rD8jyW), [2](https://ibb.co/DgtDkzh), [3](https://ibb.co/chrWJkN), [4](https://ibb.co/92vMrdN). For the code i have used the "saved_model.pb" file

Comment: For models compatability you can create new or find similar issue on [TensorFlowSharp GitHub](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues)

Answer (score 3):

I used TensorFlowSharpin the past, but that library is still stuck with TensorFlow 1.x, and development seems quite dead. Because of that, I moved on to [ML.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning).

Please see [this](https://duongnt.com/ml-net/) article about how to use ML.NET with C# (disclaimer: I was the author of that article). Below is the gist of it.

**Convert `saved_model` to `onnx`**

Install `tf2onnx`.

```
pip install tf2onnx
```

Use it to convert `saved_model` to `onnx`.

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model <path to saved_model folder> --output "model.onnx"
```

**Use ML.NET to make prediction**

Install the necessary packages.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.ML
dotnet add package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
dotnet add package Microsoft.ML.OnnxTransformer
```

Define the input and output model classes.

```
public class Input
{
    [VectorType(<input size>)]
    [ColumnName("<input node name>")]
    public float[] Data { get; set; } // Remember to change the type if your model does not use float
}

public class Output
{
    [VectorType(<output size>)]
    [ColumnName("<output node name>")]
    public float[] Data { get; set; } // Remember to change the type if your model does not use float
}
```

Load the model in `onnx` format.

```
using Microsoft.ML;

var modelPath = "<path to onnx model>";
var outputColumnNames = new[] { "<output name>" };
var inputColumnNames = new[] { "<input name>" };
var mlContext = new MLContext();
var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(outputColumnNames, inputColumnNames, modelPath);
```

Make prediction

```
var input_data= ... // code to load input into an array
var input = new Input { Data = data };

var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new[] { input });
var transformedValues = pipeline.Fit(dataView).Transform(dataView);
var output = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<Output>(transformedValues, reuseRowObject: false);

// code to use the result in output
```